# Use variables in loop which have html elements using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am creating form that have 2 div each div has 1 label and 1 text box.how i can use  created label and textbox variables in for loop . guide me.

labels and textboxes

```
var lbl1 = document.createElement(Label);
lbl1.innerHTML = "First Name";


var lbl2 = document.createElement(Label);
lbl2.innerHTML = "Last Name";


var elm1 = document.createElement(InputElement);
elm1.setAttribute("type", "text");


var elm2 = document.createElement(InputElement);
elm2.setAttribute("type", "text");

var signUpForm = document.createElement("form");
signUpForm.setAttribute("id", "signUpForm");

document.body.appendChild(signUpForm);
var getSignUpForm = document.getElementById('signUpForm');
for(var i = 1 ; i<= 2;i++)
{
    Div = document.createElement("div");
    for(var j=1;j<2;j++)
    {
        Div.appendChild("lbl"+j);
        Div.appendChild("elm"+j);
        getSignUpForm.appendChild(Div);
    }
}
```

`"lbl"+j` takes as a string not as elemt

Answer (score 0):

Use object to hold the variables and use square bracket representation `obj["lbl" + j]`. Like the following.

```js
var Label = 'label';
var InputElement = 'input';
var obj = {};
obj.lbl1 = document.createElement(Label);
obj.lbl1.innerHTML = "First Name";

obj.lbl2 = document.createElement(Label);
obj.lbl2.innerHTML = "Last Name";

obj.elm1 = document.createElement(InputElement);
obj.elm1.setAttribute("type", "text");

obj.elm2 = document.createElement(InputElement);
obj.elm2.setAttribute("type", "text");

var signUpForm = document.createElement("form");
signUpForm.setAttribute("id", "signUpForm");

document.body.appendChild(signUpForm);
var getSignUpForm = document.getElementById('signUpForm');
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  Div = document.createElement("div");
  for (var j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
    Div.appendChild(obj["lbl" + j]);
    Div.appendChild(obj["elm" + j]);
  }
  getSignUpForm.appendChild(Div);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but its not working through exception -->"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." on this line "obj.lbl1 = document.createElement(Label);"

Comment: @Rajith R Krishnan at this line --> var obj.lbl1 = document.createElement(Label);

Comment: @shujaatali have you defined values for variables `Label`, `InputElement`?

Comment: or try to use `document.createElement('label');` and `document.createElement('input');`

Comment: @Rajith R Krishnan same result bro

Comment: I added a snippet to the answer. It is working fine. I am not sure what is the issue.

Comment: @Rajith R Krishnan its working , and it was my mistake thaks again